# How to use URL Schemes in iOS8 with Today extension

Tags: ios8, url-scheme

I'm having trouble to implement URL Schemes with my today extension.

I have followed directions from the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) and when I implemented on my today extension's table view the `openURL` method, it says that the url it's not understood. The alert message shows the correct url scheme but for some reason it's not being pick up by the extension context.

So, what's the appropriate way to implement URL Schemes when using extensions?

Thanks

PS: On my app I have already configured a URL Scheme to work with Facebook, but I think that this shouldn't interfere by adding new schemes

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```

instead of

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Hope that's what you are using. I have no problem using openURL in Today Extension. If you still can't get it working with the first method, check if your URL is escape properly without any spacing